# Is there any way to embed just the view of a list on a modern page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, embedded, json-formatting

This is my list with my custom json formatting:

[image: List View Json Format]

And the embed on my modern page look like:

[image: embed on my modern page]

Is there any way to embed just the cards without command bar (and header - title - footer ...) ?? ONLY CARDS.

[image: Only view - only cards]

The querystring param isDlg=1 is not working!

Is there any other parameter that only shows the view?

Tanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Install react-script-editor web part in your site, then add the CSS style below into react script editor web part in the modern page to achieve your requirement.

Source Code from GitHub: [Script editor web part for modern pages built in React](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor)

CSS code:

```
<style>
div[class*='ms-ResizeGroup itemsViewDetailsListCommandBar']{
    display:none !important;
}
div[class*='webPartHeader_']{
    display:none !important;
}
</style>
```

[image]